# OctoberCMS Working with Arrays

Tags: php, laravel, backend, octobercms

I am having some trouble understanding how to work with arrays, I am trying to build an invoice where by it returns the price and details of an order, I have most of it working but I would like to display the items of the order. so far my code looks like this:

```
public $items;

public function prepareVars() {
    $this->items = $this->items();
}


public function items() {
    $plates = Db::table('orders')->where('quote_no', $this->quoteNo())->value('total_plate_qty');
    $hires = Db::table('orders')->where('quote_no', $this->quoteNo())->value('req_hires');
    $hardcopy = Db::table('orders')->where('quote_no', $this->quoteNo())->value('req_hardcopy_proof');
    $pdfproof = Db::table('orders')->where('quote_no', $this->quoteNo())->value('req_pdf_proof');
    if ($plates < 1) {
        $plates = "Total Plates:" . $plates;
    } else {
        $plates = "";
    }
    if ($pdfproof === 'yes') {
        $pdfproof = 'PDF Proof @ R25.00';
    } else {
        $hires = '';
    }
    if ($hires === 'yes') {
        $hires = 'HiRes PDF @ R50.00';
    } else {
        $hires = '';
    }
    if ($hardcopy === 'yes') {
        $hardcopy = 'HardCopy Proof @ R150.00';
    } else {
        $hardcopy = '';
    }
    return Response::json([
        'pdf' => $pdfproof,
        'hires' => $hires,
        'hardcopy' => $hardcopy,
        'plates' => $plates
    ]);
}
```

This is saving the data in my database like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Thu, 02 Nov 2017 08:26:11 GMT

{"pdf":"PDF Proof @ R25.00","hires":"HiRes PDF @ R50.00","hardcopy":"HardCopy Proof @ R150.00","plates":""}
```

Then on the front end I am using the twig function {%for%} and it looks like this:

```
{% set items = __SELF__.items %}
      {% for item in items %}
      <td>{{ item.pdf }}</br>{{ item.hires }}</br>{{ item.hardcopy }}</br>{{ item.plates }}</br></td>
      {% endfor %}
```

But this does not return anything on the front end.

This feels like I am doing it all wrong as I am a noob with backend dev :P 
Any help with be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am not useing OctoberCMS but i thinkyou must decode the items json like this `{% set items = json_decode(__SELF__.items) %}` and test !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't need to convert it to JSON as you not need to work with Javascript

so simply replace your code

```
return Response::json([
    'pdf' => $pdfproof,
    'hires' => $hires,
    'hardcopy' => $hardcopy,
    'plates' => $plates
]);
```

with this :

```
return [
    [
        'pdf' => $pdfproof,
        'hires' => $hires,
        'hardcopy' => $hardcopy,
        'plates' => $plates
    ]
];
```

as in template you are looping through items so you need to send it an array. its all php code so no need for json.

we return master array(**items**) which do have its items and when we loop through master array we  get its items each time(**item**)

if you need any further help please comment.